# Toggle visiblity for multiple Entities on click?

Tags: aframe

I'm looking for the easiest way to toggle visibility of multiple objects on a single entity click?

I have one main entity that the user can click on, and I want two additional entities to appear once they click the main one.

Have been researching all kinds of aframe plugins, including the aframe-event-set, but simply can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The [event-set-component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/blob/master/components/event-set/dist/aframe-event-set-component.js) grabs one target, so i'd suggest making your own [component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/component.html#register-a-component), which will grab all entities you want to toggle, and hide / show them in a for loop:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    let toggle = false
    this.el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let cylinders = document.querySelectorAll("a-cylinder")
      cylinders.forEach(function(el) {
          el.setAttribute("visible", toggle)
      })
      toggle = !toggle
    })
  }
})
```

On click, i set the visibility to all cylinders, and switch the toggle.

Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wej9usx/1/).